# insert a large number of rows in the firebird database

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

Firebird 2.5 with IB Expert.

I have an SQL script to add a large number of rows in the database

```
execute block as declare ID2 int; begin
EXECUTE PROCEDURE NEW_PROCEDURE('1', '33001', 'be0ad759-ee6a-4a21-b5f9-ed71f1eba54c00', 'Новое оборудование') returning_values :ID2;
EXECUTE PROCEDURE NEW_PROCEDURE2('1', :ID2, '13.10.2016', 'От 13.10.2016 № 1', 'Поступления');
EXECUTE PROCEDURE NEW_PROCEDURE2('1', :ID2, '13.10.2016', 'В составе Новое оборудование, в составе Новое оборудование', 'В составе');
EXECUTE PROCEDURE NEW_PROCEDURE('1', '3200', '91403ed6-56af-4acf-b66e-50c10118e4e60', 'Новое оборудование') returning_values :ID2;
EXECUTE PROCEDURE NEW_PROCEDURE2('1', :ID2, '13.10.2016', 'От 13.10.2016 № 1', 'Поступления');
EXECUTE PROCEDURE NEW_PROCEDURE2('1', :ID2, '13.10.2016', 'В составе Новое оборудование', 'В составе');
EXECUTE PROCEDURE NEW_PROCEDURE('1', '33010', 'be0ad759-ee6a-4a21-b5f9-ed71f1eba54c01', 'Новое оборудование') returning_values :ID2;
EXECUTE PROCEDURE NEW_PROCEDURE2('1', :ID2, '13.10.2016', 'От 13.10.2016 № 1', 'Поступления');
EXECUTE PROCEDURE NEW_PROCEDURE2('1', :ID2, '13.10.2016', 'В составе Новое оборудование, в составе Новое оборудование', 'В составе');
+100K
end
```

as can be seen from the example of code data are almost identical, but the error output

```
Invalid token.
Dynamic SQL Error.
SQL error code = -104.
Unexpected end of command - line 489, column 87.
```

Comment: Don't know Firebird but if every procedure run correctly one by one, I would guess that you are encountering a Memory error. I had this on other server with a huge insert. The transaction took to much place, one of the temp table was full (can't remember which one). I had to cut this into smaller transaction (10K insert per transaction).

Answer (score 3):

Given the number of lines you mention (100K), your statement size exceeds 64 kilobytes (which is the maximum statement size in Firebird 2.5 and earlier). An `execute block` is a single statement, so you need to reduce the number of statements in the execute block so it fits in 64 kilobytes.

Firebird 3 allows larger statements, but only when executed with the new API, so that won't help when executing from IB Expert.

Alternatively, the same error can also be caused when your query tool uses the semicolon as the default statement terminator. Firebird executes per statement, so most query tools will split on the semi-colon to send statements one by one. However an `execute block` internally also uses semi-colons. This means that instead of the full `execute block`, it only sends

```
execute block as declare ID2 int
```

as a statement, which is not a complete statement, which causes Firebird to report an *Unexpected end of command*-error.

To be able to execute this, you need to instruct your query tool to switch the statement terminator. For most Firebird tools this is `set term`, eg `set term #;` will switch the tools statement terminator to `#`.

You need to execute as:

```
set term #;

execute block as 
  declare ID2 int; 
begin
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE NEW_PROCEDURE('1', '33001', 'be0ad759-ee6a-4a21-b5f9-ed71f1eba54c00', 'Новое оборудование') returning_values :ID2;
  ...
end#

set term ;#
```

See also [`SET TERM` terminator or terminating character](http://ibexpert.net/ibe/index.php?n=Doc.StoredProcedureAndTriggerLanguage?from=Doc.If#SetTerm).

Comment: Given the line number in error message (489) I'd say it is more likely the statement size... if the statement terminator would be the reason, sure the line number would be 1 (or 2 or 3, depends how the statement is actually formatted).

Comment: I tried to use your proposed option, but it still gives an error

Comment: the total number of records added 3700

Comment: I reduced the number of rows to 190 and my scripts run

Comment: @fedormoore Then it is my final comment: you are exceeding maximum statement size with your execute block.

Comment: @fedormoore I have rephrased my answer so the statement size cause is mentioned first.